# I can't read the text embedded in a graph label via selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I don't know how to read the text inside the label: "Industry Avg 1.1x".

This is the website: https://simplywall.st/stocks/us/energy/nyse-hal/halliburton#valuation
The element: `<text fill="#1B222D" font-size="13" transform="translate(-111 0)">Industry Avg 1.1x</text>`

I really don't know how to address to that element in order to get the text.

Image of the graph with the label with the needed information:

[image: figure 1]

I hope somebody can help.

Thanks a lot,

Christian

Comment: How were you able to bypass the **Continue to Simply Wall St
stock analysis tool** popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That label doesn't appear until you've scrolled it into view.  I think the easiest way is to scroll all the way to the bottom, at which point the element can be found. It's tricky though because you have to scroll "like a user would". To do that, I believe the following should work, although it is far from optimized:

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight-1000);")
        # Wait to load the page.
        driver.implicitly_wait(3) # seconds
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
        driver.implicitly_wait(3) # seconds
```

Probably scratch the above. I found you can identify the section surrounding the element and click it to make your element appear. Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('section[data-cy-id=report-sub-section-price-to-earnings-ratio-vs-industry]').click()
```

Then, to identify the element and get the text, try the following:

```
text_you_want = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('g > text[font-size="13"]')[1].innerHTML
```

Comment: Thank C. Peck for your prompt answer! I've tried and got this message: 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: 5 matching elements, the desired is the second element.

Comment: @ChristianTovazzi, see my edit which includes a different way to make that element show

Comment: Thanks C. Peck, I got the same message: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Great C. Peak! You solved! I've just removed '.innerHTML' at the end. I'm still fighting in order to click the 'dropdown-vsIndustry-multiple-selection' in order to change to 'Price to Book' view.

Comment: I've tried to change in: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('section[data-cy-id=report-sub-section-price-to-book-ratio-vs-industry]').click() but it doesn't work.